# Direct access of protected JSF pages doesn't work by using HTTPS

Tags: jsf, tomcat, ssl, https

Today I started to implement SSL in my Java EE project. Everything worked fine until I tried to directly access a protected area with an logged out customer. Instead of being redirected to the log in page, a single question mark appeared.

[image: Request protected page displays just a question mark instead of the login page]

1. This behavior only produces FireFox, IE works fine
2. Without SSL, also FireFox works fine.

I'm using Tomcat 7.0 and JSF 2.1
The protected pages are:

1. Everything within SubDir /admin  needs role ADMIN to be accessible
2. Everything within SubDir /customer  needs role CUST to be accessible

The strange thing is that this question mark is displayed only by accessing some of the pages in SubDir /customer  ! By trying to access all others (including those in /admin) the Login page is displayed correctly (All pages are structured in the same way).

Finally, I brought the web site up and running correctly by using the TCP port 443 instead of 8443. Now both browsers correctly display the login page before someone is able to access a protected page.

So my question. Does anyone have any idea why this behavior occurs if port 8443 is used? And is there a way that port 8443 can still be used?

Below you can find the tomcats server.xml file. 
Thanks in advance!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server
    port="8005"
    shutdown="SHUTDOWN" >

    <Listener
        SSLEngine="on"
        className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" />

    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />

    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />

    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />

    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

    <GlobalNamingResources>

        <Resource
            name="UserDatabase"
            auth="Container"
            description="User database that can be updated and saved"
            factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
            pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml"
            type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase" />
    </GlobalNamingResources>

    <Service name="Catalina" >

        <Connector
            connectionTimeout="20000"
            port="8080"
            protocol="HTTP/1.1"
            redirectPort="443" />

        <Connector
            SSLEnabled="true"
            clientAuth="false"
            keystoreFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-tomcat-7.0.30\conf\BookStore.keystore"
            keystorePass="myPwd"
            maxThreads="200"
            port="443"
            protocol="HTTP/1.1"
            scheme="https"
            secure="true"
            sslProtocol="TLS" />

        <Connector
            port="8009"
            protocol="AJP/1.3"
            redirectPort="443" />

        <Engine
            name="Catalina"
            defaultHost="localhost" >

            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm" >

                <Realm
                    className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
                    resourceName="UserDatabase" />
            </Realm>

            <Realm
                className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
                connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/bookstore?user=bookstore&amp;password=book$tore"
                driverName="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"
                roleNameCol="role"
                userCredCol="pwd"
                userNameCol="eMail"
                userRoleTable="roles"
                userTable="customer" />

            <Host
                name="localhost"
                appBase="webapps"
                autoDeploy="true"
                unpackWARs="true" >

                <Valve
                    className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
                    directory="logs"
                    pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"
                    prefix="localhost_access_log."
                    suffix=".txt" />

                <Context
                    docBase="BookStore"
                    path="/BookStore"
                    reloadable="true"
                    source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:BookStore" />
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>

</Server>
```

Answer (score 1):

That question mark appears when you're trying to use http on a https connection. You can't see what protocol you are using because the default settings within FF hide the protocol.

Enter *about:config* within the browser url and look for *browser.urlbar.trimURLs*, and set it to **false**. Now you'll see the *http://* in front of your browser url. Switch it to httpS and the question mark will disappear.

*Edit*: The url you are trying to access is shown in the tab, it's *http* instead of *https*.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited it to false. If I enter the URL: https: //localhost:8443/BookStore/faces/sections/customer/ and press enter, the browser shows: http: //localhost:8443/BookStore/faces/sections/customer/ and the question mark again. So it will be redirected quite strange to http: //localhost:8443/.../ That makes no sense for me.

Comment: You states in your question that you're using port 443 (standard port) instead of 8443. Redirect your browser to *https: //localhost:443/BookStore/faces/sections/customer/* or just *https: //localhost/BookStore/faces/sections/customer/*. Also try to add following parameter to your ssl connector: *keystoreType="JKS"* and *URIEncoding="UTF-8"*. (if it fits your keystore)